Show embedded Openstreetmap in a full window
How can I show a custom Openstreetmap (which means there are customs pins in it) that has been embedded into a website in a normal Openstreetmap window? The embedded map is in such a small frame, that it is not possible to print a bigger version, so I want to show the map in a bigger window. In the code I could not find any source link of the map...
https://www.stolpersteine-stuttgart.de/kartenueberblick/
